# bot insert a command in the question discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i need a help. Why does the bot insert a command in the question? Here is the code for my polls:

```py
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx):
    questions = ctx.message.content.split("&&")

    question2=questions[0]
    option1=questions[1]
    option2=questions[2]
    option3=questions[3]


    em=discord.Embed(title=f"{question2}", description="")
    em.add_field(name="nothing", value=f"{option1} \n {option2} \n {option3}")
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

and this is how looks my polls (i don't want "s!poll" in my question, and i don't writing "s!poll" in question):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vEBO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `message.content`, which is **the entire message**, *including* your command. If you don't want the prefix or command to be included, use `arguments` instead.

```py
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, text):
    questions = text.split("&&")
```

Also, instead of `split`ting on `&&`, you can change it up a bit to make it look like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, question, option1, option2, option3):
```

and call it like this, putting every sentence between `"quotes"` so Discord knows which argument starts where:

```
!poll "question here" "option1 here" "option2 here" "option3 here"
```

More info on how parameters work in the [`API Docs`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=argument#parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code a bit. First about the error:

```py
questions = ctx.message.content.split("&&")
question2 = questions[0]
```

Also includes the command itself. ***Instead you could put some conditions:***

```py
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, title=None, option1=None, option2=None, option3=None):
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{title}", description="")
    em.add_field(name="nothing", value=f"{option1} \n {option2} \n {option3}")
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Your command would be corresponding:

```py
!poll "Test title" "Question1" "Question2" "Question3"
```

If a user does not enter anything for a question it is automatically `None`.